# Spacing multiple TextViews of different sizes in a row

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, spacing, ios-autolayout

I want to maintain the correct proportion of spacing between 5 TextViews of different sizes in a UIView. Here is what it looks like in the editor:

[image]

The constraints on each of the 5 TextViews are on the top, bottom, leading, and trailing space to either the superview or the TextView next to it. Additionally, I selected all 5 TextViews and gave them all the "Aspect Ratio" constraint.

Here is what it looks like when the simulator is tilted to be landscape:

[image]

These spacing proportions between the TextViews are as I want them.

Here is what it looks like when the simulator is tilted to be portrait:

[image]

It appears to me that the size of the 4 right TextViews, as well as the spacing between them, is unchanged, while the size of just the leftmost TextView shrunk considerably. This cuts of the text of the leftmost TextView and makes all of the TextViews appear close together.

Instead, I would like to maintain the aspect ratio of all of the TextViews, so that what I would expect to happen is that the 4 right TextViews get truncated a bit but the proportional spacing between everything looks the same as in landscape mode.

Comment: Have you tried setting the leftmost TextView's aspect ratio constraint priority to be higher than the other 4?

Comment: @DicksonLeonard When I do this, the rightmost TextViews get pushed entirely off the screen

Comment: can you show the constraints given for all the 5 items?